# cross2() vs cross_df() to make a tibble with purrr

Tags: r, purrr

I think I am misunderstanding how `purrr::cross_df()` is supposed to work.

As an example, lets say that I have 20 stores and 104 weeks. I would like to make a tibble that has stores and weeks as the columns. The resulting tibble should be 2 columns by 20*104 rows to represent all store weeks.

The way I approached this was

```
stores <- 1:20
weeks <- 1:104
cross2(stores,weeks)
```

the problem is that I would like this to be a tibble not lists. I tried using replacing `cross` with `cross_df`, but I did not have any success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you make a named list, you can pass it into `cross_df`:

```r
library(purrr)

list(stores = 1:20, weeks = 1:104) %>% cross_df()
#> # A tibble: 2,080 x 2
#>    stores weeks
#>     <int> <int>
#>  1      1     1
#>  2      2     1
#>  3      3     1
#>  4      4     1
#>  5      5     1
#>  6      6     1
#>  7      7     1
#>  8      8     1
#>  9      9     1
#> 10     10     1
#> # ... with 2,070 more rows
```

You *could* use `cross2`, but you'd need to coerce it to a data frame afterwards. The primary issue is that the resulting list elements don't have names, so you'd need to re-add them to coerce to a data frame, e.g.

```r
stores <- 1:20
weeks <- 1:104

cross2(stores, weeks) %>% map_df(set_names, c('stores', 'weeks'))
```

The longer explanation is that `cross2` does a Cartesian (cross) join of the vectors you pass it, while `cross` does the same with the elements of the list you pass it. `cross_df` is a version of `cross` which simplifies to a data frame afterwards, parallel to `map_df`.

Also worth noting is that base R already has an excellent function for doing a cross join and getting a data frame in `expand.grid`:

```r
df <- expand.grid(stores = stores, weeks = weeks)

head(df)
#>   stores weeks
#> 1      1     1
#> 2      2     1
#> 3      3     1
#> 4      4     1
#> 5      5     1
#> 6      6     1
```

If you pass in vectors, you have to name them if you want to retain names, but it will take a named list like `cross`, as well, and retain its names, e.g.

```r
df <- list(stores = 1:20, weeks = 1:104) %>% expand.grid()
```

All results are the same, with the exception that `expand.grid` returns a vanilla data.frame instead of a tibble.